# Trash won't open on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: linux, nautilus

Rhythmbox had double links to all my mp3s because I moved folders and I wanted to get it to rescan so I highlighted everything and clicked "Move to Trash." Now I want to undo this, but Trash won't open. top output doesn't even indicate that nautilus is taking up resources.

Please let me know if you have any ideas before I restore from backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate to the Trash by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in a folder window and entering `trash://`.

Comment: I had to restore from backup, but thanks for the shortcut